# Get data from array to array in magento 2

Tags: magento2

This is my array

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "10"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "22"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "25"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "37"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "38"
}
```

How to get it to array like this

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "10"
    }
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "22"
    }
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "25"
    }
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "37"
    }
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "38"
}
```

I'm using this code

```
$sellerIds = * My Array *

if(is_array($sellerIds)){
    foreach($sellerIds as $key => $value){
         $sellerIds = $value;
    }
}
// do something with $sellerIds
```

But when i var_dump it, it like this

```
string(2) "10"
string(2) "22"
...
```

Please Help Me ! Thanks All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using array_chunk function :-**

```
print_r(array_chunk($input_array,1,true)); //pass your Array
```

[array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=array("10","22","25","37","38");

$finalArrays=(array_chunk($array, 1,true));

foreach($finalArrays as $value)

{

  var_dump($value);

}
```